# Python building PCA with multiple classifications

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am tyrying to build a 3D PCA plot using data clasified with 5 different classifications but keep getting an error.

data:

```
d = {'A':[1,4,6,3,4,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,2,5,6],'B':[3,4,6,6,5,4,7,8,9,0,0,0,1,2,3],
     'C':[3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5], 'D':[3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4],
     'E':[1,1,0,9,1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,7,6,5],'F':[1,1,1,1,3,4,7,6,5,4,3,4,5,6,7],
     'disease':[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,2,2,3]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


X = frame.loc[:,'A':'F'].to_numpy() # change this based on the subset of biomarkers
y = np.ravel(frame.loc[:,['disease']], order='C')

sc = StandardScaler()

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X) 
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)


pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(X_scaled) 
X_pca = pca.transform(X_scaled) 

ex_variance=np.var(X_pca,axis=0)
ex_variance_ratio = ex_variance/np.sum(ex_variance)
ex_variance_ratio


Xax = X_pca[:,0]
Yax = X_pca[:,1]
Zax = X_pca[:,2]


cdict = {0:'green',1:'red',2:'yellow',3:'blue',4:'pink'}
labl = {0:'Healthy',1:'Stage1',2:'Stage2',3:'Stage3',4:'Stage4'}
marker = {0:'o',1:'o',2:'o',3:'o',4:'o'}
alpha = {0:.3, 1:.5}

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
for l in np.unique(y):
 ix=np.where(y==l)
 ax.scatter(Xax[ix], Yax[ix], Zax[ix], c=cdict[l], s=40,
           label=labl[l], marker=marker[l], alpha=alpha[l])
# for loop ends
ax.set_xlabel("PC1", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("PC2", fontsize=14)
ax.set_zlabel("PC3", fontsize=14)
ax.set_title('TCGA PDAC Stage3 Biomarker Set - RF')
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

But this results in the following error:

```
KeyError: 2
```

Any help would be great.

The desired output is a PCA plot with the different clusters shown.

Comment: error is here `alpha=alpha[l]`

Comment: strange, heres the error message in total:  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-240-38abb637b0e4> in <module>
     35  ix=np.where(y==l)
     36  ax.scatter(Xax[ix], Yax[ix], Zax[ix], c=cdict[l], s=40,
---> 37            label=labl[l], marker=marker[l], alpha=alpha[l])
     38 # for loop ends
     39 ax.set_xlabel("PC1", fontsize=14)

KeyError: 2

Comment: Ignore me, I didn't scroll down the code snippet. Mehmaam has found your issue though, alpha doesn't have a key of 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to add values for keys `2, 3` and `4` in `alpha`.
Such as:

```
alpha = {0:.3, 1:.5, 2:.7, 3:.9, 4:1}
```